# Unbalanced ANOVA, R possibly disregarding duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe, row

After running a one-way ANOVA on my dataset, I noticed that it's reporting the results as unbalanced despite having even numbers of entries for every variable.

Then, using ezPrecis to look at the dataframe, it seems that some values are not being counted despite having the correct number of rows registered. For example, using just method C from id 1, it says there's 46 values in ct even though it registers 50 rows (and has 50 values under ct). Is it possible that R is disregarding the duplicate values? Because looking at the raw file, there's 4 400's and 2 1684's. If you eliminate the duplicates, then that's precisely 4 items not counted which lines up with the 46 counted ct's when viewing through ezPrecis. Is this why the Anova is unbalanced? If so, how do you fix it?

```
library(ez)

data1 <- read.csv("data.csv")

data1

data1$id <- as.character(data1$id)
data1$id <- as_factor(data1$id)
data1$method <- as_factor(data1$method)

ezPrecis(data1)

ezDesign(data=data1, x=method, y=id)

data2 <- data1 %>% 
  group_by(method) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(ct, na.rm = TRUE),
        sd = sd(ct, na.rm = TRUE),
        se = sd(ct)/sqrt(length(ct)))
data2

data2anova <- ezANOVA(data=data1, dv=ct, wid=id, within=.(method),type=3, 
detailed=TRUE, return_aov=TRUE)
data2anova
```

Raw data: https://ufile.io/cfe1w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the rows are used in the ANOVA. The `ezPrecis` function informs you of the number of unique values in the column. This is clear from the help for the function where it refers to the "values" column as "unique." Why that column name got changed to "values" is anyone's guess.

The output from the ANOVA says "Estimated effects **may** be unbalanced". The replications for each variable, such as calculated using the `replications` function, is likely being inspected during the `aov` processing and warning the user that there could be unbalance present.

Your data frame yields the following:

```
replications(~ . - ct, data=data1)

       id    method testblock     trial 
      150       100        60        30
```